# How can I check which PyKX version I have installed?

Tags: pykx

How can I check which PyKX version I have installed?

I've tried

```
PyKX version

PyKX --version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `import` in Python you can view that with:

```
pykx.__version__
```

From the command line you can call:

```
pip show pykx
```